# Cannot find method - Error when upgrading kotlin-gradle-plugin from 1.6.21 to 1.7.10

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error,

```
Unable to find method ''org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceTask org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.source(java.lang.Object[])''
'org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceTask org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.source(java.lang.Object[])'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

when upgrading kotlin-gradle-plugin from 1.6.21 to 1.7.10 in project level build.gradle file in an android project.

AS version is - **2021.2.1 patch 1**

com.android.tools.build:gradle:**7.2.1**

Current kotlin plugin version installed in AS - **212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46**

None of the suggestions working :((

Comment: I have reported this issue right there in android studio and now I can upgrade kotlin plugin  as easy as changing version number variable. Now it's fixed by them only.

Comment: I've opened an issue regarding this on their bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54540/Upgrading-kotlin-version-from-1610-to-170-causes-gradle-build-to-fail-on-android-project

Comment: Did anyone ever manage to resolve this? I'm still having this issue with `1.7.20`

Comment: It got resolved automatically when I tried again after several restarts. I am still not sure what caused them..

Comment: I had to update `com.google.devtools.ksp`.

Answer (score 11):

I got the same issue, in my case upgrading the apollo dependency to the last version solved the issue.

```
object Apollo {
    const val APOLLO_RUNTIME = "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:2.5.13"
    const val APOLLO_RX = "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-rx2-support:2.5.13"
}


api(Libs.Apollo.APOLLO_RUNTIME)
implementation(Libs.Apollo.APOLLO_RX)
```

Upgrade your dependencies to the last version and sync again.

Comment: This is confirming..I am also using the apollo library ..But I have not upgraded all of them at once..but in different rounds..Then after I upgraded apollo and then eventually when I upgraded the Gradle. This is solved...

Comment: yes this error goes away on downgrading apollo to 2.5.13

Answer (score -1):

Check at build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.0-rc02'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false // <--- Change this one to 1.7.10 
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```